# python breaking out of loop

Tags: python, loops

I don't know how to break out of the loop. The program is asking my user the same question two times, and I cannot work out why. it should ask me which team won the event only ONE time, then ask me, 'is this correct' but then it asks again who won

```
import time
class Team:
    def __init__(self, num, name, size, score):
        self.num = num
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.score = score

    def add_victory(self):
        self.score += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.num} |-| Team Name: {self.name} |-| Member Count: {self.size} |-| Team Score: {self.score}'

def NewTournament():

    TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

    print('')
    for i in range(TeamCounter):
        NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
        MemberCount=int(input('How Many Members in Team? '))
        print('')
        teams.append( Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )


def Score(teams):
    winner = input('Which Team Won the Event? ')
    for team in teams:
        if team.name == winner:
            team.add_victory()
            break
            print('Updated Leaderboard')

def Leaderboard():
    for t in teams:
        print(t)
    
def Menu():
    MenuLoop=1
    while MenuLoop==1:
        print('1.Create Tournament')
        print('2.Update Existing Tournament')
        print('3.View Leaderboard')
        print('4.Exit')
        MenuOption=input('')
        if MenuOption=='1':
            print('Creating Tournament')
            NewTournament()#runs the new tournament function
            MenuLoop-=1
            Menu()
        elif MenuOption=='2':
            print('Updating Tournament')
            MenuLoop-=1
            EventName=input('Which Event Was Completed? ')
            winner=input('Which Team Won the Event? ')#asking me this 2 times
            print('Event Winner:', winner, '||', 'Event:',EventName)
            print('Is this correct? Y/N') 
            Check=input('')
            if Check=='y':
                print('Updating Leaderboard')
                Score(teams)
                Menu()
                    
                
                
        elif MenuOption=='3':
            MenuLoop-=1
            Leaderboard()
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            Menu()
                
        elif MenuOption=='4':
            print('Exiting Program...')
        else:
            print('Error, please choose an option from the list below.')#keeps looping if user is not choosing a correct number from list


#start of program
teams = []        

print('░██╗░░░░░░░██╗███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░░███╗███████╗')
print('░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░████║██╔════╝')
print('░╚██╗████╗██╔╝█████╗░░██║░░░░░██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██╔████╔██║█████╗░░')
print('░░████╔═████║░██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██║░░██╗██║░░██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══╝░░')
print('░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░███████╗███████╗╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚═╝░██║███████╗')
print('░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚══════╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚══════╝')#welcome user
print('')
Username=input('Enter Username: ')
Password=input('Enter Password: ')
if Username =='Admin' and Password == 'Admin':#very basic login system for security of school
    print('Logging in...')
    print('User Verified')
    Menu()
else:
    print('User Does Not Exist.')#stops pupils gaining unauthorised access
```

I get this output:

```
1.Create Tournament
2.Update Existing Tournament
3.View Leaderboard
4.Exit
2
Updating Tournament
Which Event Was Completed? Football
Which Team Won the Event? Two
Event Winner: Two || Event: Football
Is this correct? Y/N
y
Updating Leaderboard
Which Team Won the Event? Two
1.Create Tournament
2.Update Existing Tournament
3.View Leaderboard
4.Exit
3
```

It loops back to the `menu()` as I would like, but I do not like how it is asking me 'which team won the event?' twice. It should only be once.

Comment: There is only one question 'Is this correct?` in your output.

Comment: damn, i meant 'which team won the event?' my apoligies

Comment: First of all, why the weird logic with having both a `while` loop AND calling `Menu()` recursively?

Comment: im new to pyton, in my head this makes sense. the loop is so that if they enter something that is not 'Y' or 'N' then the program will ask the user the question again as it is an invalid response.

Comment: And why can't you do the same for options 1-3?

Comment: If you try to follow your code, you will clearly notice that you do tell the program to print it twice - once in `Menu()` and once in `Score()`

Comment: i seeeee, im so stupid. i have removed the winner=input... from score. but now it cant get the 'winner' variable. how can i call this from menu?

Comment: You seem to know how to pass `teams` variable, what stops you from doing that to another variable?

Comment: can you show me what you mean? my code is messy and i would appreciate seeing how it would look neater :) @matszwecja

Answer (score 0):

So made a few adjustments:

1. You get asked `'Which Team Won the Event?'` twice because you literally have it in there twice: once in the Menu() MenuOption 2, and then Score() which you call in that same option 2. So you need to decide which one to keep. I kept the one in the Menu(), then pass that `winner` input into the `Score()` function
2. A better way to handle the loop here is simply have the `while` loop continue while the `MenuOption != '4'`
3. You need to fix your `Check`. You ask the user to input uppercase `Y/N`, but then you `if Check=='y'`. So even if the user enters `Y`, `Check=='y'` will return `False`. Also to that point, why the separate `print()` followed by `input`? Just combine that.
4. You added a `print()` statement after `break` in `Score()`? You realize then everything after a `break` won't run?
5. Having the Menu() function with the Menu() function. Calling that recursively will keep you in the while loop when you're expecting it to jump out.

So made those few changes. I'd suggest find/use and IDE that can let you debug and run the code line by line, so that you can sort of follow your code/logic. PyCharm is very popular one. I use Spyder.

```
import time
class Team:
    def __init__(self, num, name, size, score):
        self.num = num
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.score = score

    def add_victory(self):
        self.score += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.num} |-| Team Name: {self.name} |-| Member Count: {self.size} |-| Team Score: {self.score}'

def NewTournament():

    TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

    print('')
    for i in range(TeamCounter):
        NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
        MemberCount=int(input('How Many Members in Team? '))
        print('')
        teams.append( Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )


def Score(teams, winner):
    for team in teams:
        if team.name == winner:
            team.add_victory()
            print('Updated Leaderboard')
            break

def Leaderboard():
    for t in teams:
        print(t)
    
def Menu():
    MenuOption = False
    while MenuOption!='4':
        print('1.Create Tournament')
        print('2.Update Existing Tournament')
        print('3.View Leaderboard')
        print('4.Exit')
        MenuOption=input('')
        if MenuOption=='1':
            print('Creating Tournament')
            NewTournament()#runs the new tournament function
            
        elif MenuOption=='2':
            print('Updating Tournament')
            EventName=input('Which Event Was Completed? ')
            winner=input('Which Team Won the Event? ')#asking me this 2 times
            print('Event Winner:', winner, '||', 'Event:',EventName)
            Check=input('Is this correct? Y/N\n') 
            if Check.upper()=='Y':
                print('Updating Leaderboard')
                Score(teams, winner)
                
        elif MenuOption=='3':
            Leaderboard()
            print('')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            
                
        elif MenuOption=='4':
            print('Exiting Program...')
        else:
            print('Error, please choose an option from the list below.')#keeps looping if user is not choosing a correct number from list


#start of program
teams = []        

print('░██╗░░░░░░░██╗███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░░███╗███████╗')
print('░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░████║██╔════╝')
print('░╚██╗████╗██╔╝█████╗░░██║░░░░░██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██╔████╔██║█████╗░░')
print('░░████╔═████║░██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██║░░██╗██║░░██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══╝░░')
print('░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░███████╗███████╗╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚═╝░██║███████╗')
print('░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚══════╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚══════╝')#welcome user
print('')
Username=input('Enter Username: ')
Password=input('Enter Password: ')
if Username =='Admin' and Password == 'Admin':#very basic login system for security of school
    print('Logging in...')
    print('User Verified')
    Menu()
else:
    print('User Does Not Exist.')#stops pupils gaining unauthorised access
```